# Docker: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob

Tags: python, azure, docker

I have this code running fine on my personal computer

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(file_sas)
```

This is my local envir:

```
python --version
Python 3.10.4

$ pip show azure.storage.blob
Name: azure-storage-blob
Version: 12.14.1
```

I have a docker image where I force the same version of `azure.storage.blob: Version: 12.14.1`. However, my python version is different.

```
# python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

And in docker I have the following error:

```
>>> from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/__init__.py)
```

Any help welcome

Comment: Try to uninstall and then reinstall the module. Try to upgrade to newer version.

Comment: If it is 3.8 try to use BlockBlobService Package

Comment: Can you give me full code and proper process?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my docker image contained a previous older version of the package.

```
RUN sudo pip uninstall azure-storage-blob -y
RUN python3 -m pip install azure-storage-blob
```

Fixed it for me